# Parsing with ANTLR in the ace editor

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4, ace-editor

Using the antlr4-ace-ext tokenizer for the ace editor, is it possible to access the parser associated with the ace session so that I could navigate the parse tree as if I were going to compile the source in the editor? My project is configured almost identically to https://github.com/maiermic/antlr4-javascript-examples/tree/master/browser-example.

I have looked through the ace api and didn't find a way to access the worker from the session. Alternatively, I guess I could just retrieve the source from the editor and set up a second parser.